# Prolog go through all lists of a list

Tags: prolog

I would like to make the following piece of code work without using maplist.

```
only_two([Person|Choice]) :- subset([red, red], Choice), not(subset([red, red, red], Choice).
only_two([[Person|Choice]|Others]) :- only_two([Person|Choice]), only_two(Others).
```

Then I have

```
?-only_two([John, red, blue, blue, green, red]).    -> True
?-only_two([[John, red, blue, blue, green, red],
            [Alice, green, red, red, blue, green],
            [Fred, red, red, blue, yellow, green]]).   -> False
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Why no maplist?

Comment: It's in the statement given to me

Comment: But you are allowed to use subset/2?

Comment: Yes we have access to both subset/1 and subset/2.